# how to generate table relationship schematic/entity relationship for an existing database

Tags: sql-server

I just got access to a sql server 2005 database, however we don't have the table relationships.

Where can I get a program to generate this schematic for me?

Thanks
Bruce

Comment: Do you mean building the relationships in between the tables? There is nothing can predict which table is related to which.

Comment: Enterprise Elements has this kind of tool, but it works on Oracle only.  @mohammedn - it works by analyzing the foreign key constraints

Comment: Basically a diagram showing relationship between tables using foreing keys.

Comment: If you already have the existing FK/PK relationships, try the enterprise manager that comes with SQLServer. Click on your DB then Database Diagrams

Comment: @CResults: it's called **SQL Server Management Studio** in SQL Server 2005 (and newer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

Microsoft Visio :)